# Cómo obtengo una variable de .serialize(); de mi from?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
var frm2 = $("#chat_form").serialize();
```

quiero solo obtener por ejemplo el valor del `input` `con nombre hola`

como podria obtenerlo?

Comment: Haz intentado con `$('#inputId').val()`

Comment: no es lo que busco, pero creo que si me acordaste de algo

Comment: nop, ya que si tengo varios cuadros a la vez con el mismo id, no me va a servir

Comment: Puedes utilizar entonces clases $('.inputClass').val()

Comment: esque van a ser varias cosas con lo mismo.

Comment: Entonces completa tu código con lo que intentas hacer.

Comment: Sobre lo que mencionas en tu comentario, "nop, ya que si tengo varios cuadros a la vez con el mismo id, no me va a servi" Básicamente no debes tener dos o más elementos con el mismo id. Es por eso que te cuesta obtener el valor de uno en particular. Lo que si puedes tener es "n" cantidad de elementos con la misma clase pero nunca con el mismo id

Comment: Quieres obtener el valor de un elemento luego de que enviaste el formulario o en el mismo formulario antes del envio? Este link podría ayudarte [serialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479924/how-to-access-jquery-serialized-data)

Comment: cuando envio el formulario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes obtenerlo de esta  manera

```
let valor = $("#chat_form")[0].elements.hola.value;
```

Comment: gracias, me salvaste la vida :"v

Comment: me da un error     chat_conversar.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined
    at chat_cargar_mensajes (chat_convesar.js:37)//está el código
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: Verifica que exista el elemento y que sea un <form>
Si lo estas obteniendo sin jquery sería de la sig. manera:
let valor = document.getElementById("chat_form").elements.hola.value;

Comment: chat_conversar.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of null
    at chat_cargar_mensajes (chat_conversar.js:32)
    at <anonymous>:1:1     //EN TODOS, PUESTO O NO

Comment: Ya no solucione con un if, gracias